# Setting up and inserting into multiple related tables using SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have multiple related tables in a star-schema format that look like the following:

```
FACT TABLE
==========
id (primary key)
globalattribute1
globalattribute2

DIMENSION TABLE 1
==========
id (foreign key to fact_table.id)
specificattribute1
specificatrribute2

DIMENSION TABLE 2
==========
id (foreign key to fact_table.id)
specificattribute1
specificatrribute2
```

Here's what I have so far in my Python code (in addition to the Base, session . Can you offer any suggestions on this?

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import *
engine = create_engine('mysql://...')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()

class Fact(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'fact_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    global1 = Column(String(255))
    global2 = Column(String(255))


    #Constructor

class Dimension1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dimension1'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('fact_table.id'))
    specific1 = Column(String(255))
    specific2 = Column(String(255))

    #Constructor

class Dimension2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dimension2'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('fact_table.id'))
    specific1 = Column(String(255))
    specific2 = Column(String(255))

    #Constructor

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

How do I use this to insert one record that would contain both global attirbutes and specific attributes for one of the dimension tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to have both `Dimension1` and `Dimension2` to have a One-To-One relationship with `Fact`? In that case you might want to look at [One-To-One](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_6/orm/relationships.html#one-to-one) relationship configuration.

```
class Fact(Base):
    ...
    dim1 = relationship('Dimension1', uselist=False)
    dim2 = relationship('Dimension2', uselist=False)


    #Constructor
```

Additionally you might want to look at [association proxies](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html). I haven't used them, but as far as I understand, they can be used to specify a foreign attribute directly instead of havin to do e.g. `fact.dim1.specific1`

I hope this answers your quesion. If you do not want One-To-One, take a look at the other available relationships and see what fits.

To add a new fact do this:

```
fact = Fact(...)
fact.dim1 = Dimension1(...)
fact.dim2 = Dimension2(...)
session.add(fact)
```

This will automatically emit all necessary queries on `session.commit` (or however you do transactions). For more detail maybe you should additionally read [Using The Session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html).

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply!! I'm wondering; is a one-to-one across multiple tables still a one-to-one? Can you recommend a resource on this?

I can't change the schema because it was given to me and I need to implement around it. Would an insert for this look like this: 1. Insert global data into fact table 2. Get ID from fact table 3. insert id and specific data into dimension tables?

Comment: On second thought, I think this is One-To-Many relationship on the fact table side and a Many-To-One relationship on the dimension table side. In this case, if I define the relationship in the fact table as such, how do I insert into the tables using SQLalchemy? Do I have to follow the 3 steps in my previous comment? Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: You make it a One-To-One by specifying `uselist=False`. I edited my original answer to include an example